# parse Java JSONArray with jquery.parseJSON()

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

at the moment I'm parsing the string with eval()-method and it works fine, but want to parse it with the native JSON methods of a browser. Is there good way to parse the string with jquery.parseJSON() or with any other jQuery method to an array of javascript objects? The string looks like

```
[
    {
        "title": "01  Books",
        "groupId": "01",
        "groupName": "Books",
        "key": "1",
        "isFolder": true,
        "expand": false,
        "isLazy": true
    },
    {
        "title": "02  Music",
        "groupId": "02",
        "groupName": "Music",
        "key": "2",
        "isFolder": true,
        "expand": false,
        "isLazy": true
    }
]
```

build with net.sf.json.JSONArray of Java.

jquery.parseJSON() can just parse strings like {"Key":"Value","Key":"Value",....} I guess?

thx for your help!

Comment: as long as it's _valid_ json, it'll parse it..

Comment: I tried jsonlint.com and there it's valid. I guess there is a problem to parse a nested array?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. It is jQuery, not jquery. Capitalization is important.

```
jQuery.parseJSON()
```

or

```
$.parseJSON()
```

This is supposed to parse it into a json object.

Comment: sorry, my fault :) I wrote jQuery.parseJSON() in my code, but it throws an exception. I guess jQuery.parseJSON() can not parse an string like [{"Key":"Value","Key":"Value"},{"Key":"Value","Key":"Value"},{....}]

Comment: @joo i have used jQuery.parseJSON(result) & result is `code` {"resort0":"Abaco Beach Resort at Boat Harbour","resort1":"Alexandra Resort","room0":"1 Bedroom Luxury Oceanfront Suite","room1":"2 Bedroom Deluxe Ocean View Suite","room2":"Deluxe Garden View Studio","room3":"Deluxe Ocean View Studio","room4":"Deluxe Oceanfront","room5":"Oceanfront","room6":"Superior Oceanfront"} `code`  and works fine